# How to get Azure Storage account logging enablement status?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

According to the azure documentation I have enabled logging for my storage account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account#configure-logging

Is there any REST API to get that logging enablement information ?

Expected response :
{
"storage account name" : "st1",
"log" : "enabled"
}

I have tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnosticsettings/list API.
But it returns empty value response every time.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps [Blob Service properties using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-service-properties)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.